# Ruby on Rails Query Count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a site where users can post opinions, as well as rate opinion up or down.

In turn, I need to find a way to count opinion that have been rated up or down.

I'm currently working on those which have been rated up. I have a many-to-many relationship between the following entities: `Opinion` and `Rating`.

The two entities are joined together by a table called `OpinionRatings`. Below is the query I have come up with so far.

```
@topUpSize = OpinionRating.find(
      :first,
      :select => "count(opinion_ratings.opinion_id) as count",
      :joins => "inner join ratings on opinion_ratings.rating_id=ratings.id",
      :group => "opinion_ratings.opinion_id",
      :having => ["ratings.up=?", true]
    )
```

The problem I have is I currently have two separate test opinions that have been rated up so the count that should be displayed is two, however, the count that is displayed is one.  I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would be more effective using a counter variable, which is increased or decreased each time a user casts a vote, instead of trying to sum up the votes each time the article is accessed.

Comment: Why would you use a many-to-many relationship? Shouldnt it just be that opinions have many ratings and a rating belongs to one opinion?

Comment: I fixed the relationship to a one-to-many and got the count to work by called the size method on the array returned.

Comment: I always think most relationships are many-to-many. I don't know why. I think I over think it. For example, I was thinking that ratings can belong to many opinions.